# 'image source not readable' error occurs every time when I use intervention package

Tags: laravel, image, path, intervention, image-file

```
    $imagePath = (request('image')->store('uploads', 'public'));
     //dd($imagePath);
    $image= Image::make(public_path("storage/{$imagePath}"))->fit(1000,1000);
    $image->save();

    auth()->user()->posts()->create([
        'caption'=>$data['caption'],
        'image'=>$imagePath,
    ]);
```

this is my code the $image variable is not getting anything and it push back the error "image source not readable" kindly help me in this. Thanks in Advance :)
[image: the error]

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the stored image using the `Storage` facade.

```php
$image = Image::make(Storage::disk('public')->get($imagePath))->fit(1000,1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running `php artisan storage:link`.

It will work if storage files not accessible for intervening from the stored file.